# Running any kind of login script when sh is linked to bash

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, login

My problem: My web host offers ssh to their shared server. I want to set up a couple of aliases and such, so I'm trying to get a login script of any flavor to run. If my shell was plain bash, I would simply add my stuff to one of the dotfiles and be done with it.

Now, as it happens, my shell is specified as `/bin/sh`, which is linked to bash:

```
sh-3.2$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
sh-3.2$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
sh-3.2$
```

I've tried creating all the usual suspects, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `.login` without luck.

What can I do to execute a command on startup? Any file names I've forgotten to try? **Should** any of these work under my conditions? I.e. has my host done something to disable login script?

I'd prefer not asking my host to set a different shell for me until I've gotten my facts straight about this.

Comment: Bash, like all other shells you might find as `/bin/sh`, executes commands from `~/.profile` when you log in, unless you have a shell-specific file such as `~/.bash_profile`. What does `ps $$ $PPID` show at this shell prompt? What about `ls -ld ~/.*profile` and `echo $-`? What happens if you remove (or rename) all of the `.bash*` files, and put `set -x` at the top of `~/.profile`?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) section [6.2 Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> **Invoked with name sh**
>
> If Bash is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the posix standard as well.
>
> When invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order. The `--noprofile` option may be used to inhibit this behavior. When invoked as an interactive shell with the name `sh`, Bash looks for the variable `ENV`, expands its value if it is defined, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute. Since a shell invoked as `sh` does not attempt to read and execute commands from any other startup files, the `--rcfile` option has no effect. A non-interactive shell invoked with the name `sh` does not attempt to read any other startup files.

Answer (score 0):

You can run chsh to change your shell to /bin/bash.

> chsh -s /bin/bash

bash invoked as /bin/sh should execute your ~/.profile at logon.